# Any links to Service Broker best practices?

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

I am looking for any authoritative articles on Service Broker best practices.

In particular, I am looking for the following topics (I know the answers, but have to find documents that support the knowledge):

- queues in the same database
- message

  - size
  - systems where the message is just a pointer and data is retrieved from tables
- instrumentation - auditing Service Broker applications

TIA

Comment: http://rusanu.com/blog/

Comment: Personally I think there's a lack of useful 'real world' information about Service Broker, at least compared to other SQL Server features like SSIS. So if you already know the best practices to follow, you might consider writing some good articles yourself.

Comment: @Pondlife I may have to do just that. I am currently on an assessment project and was looking for good links, rather than use the "from my experience" perspective, but I guess I could write a blog entry, have it vetted by one my friends at Microsoft, and use it as a "best practices" article. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> systems where the message is just a pointer and data is retrieved from tables

This is not a Service Broker application, is just a queueing application. Service Broker was designed primarily for distributed applications, communication (networking, security, routing, retries) is a major component. If you only send messages as pointers and the data is in tables the distributed nature of SSB falls apart. **The litmus test is "can I move my service onto another server and the application continues to work after I fix the routing?"**. If the answer is Yes then you're using SSB the way it was designed. If is No it meas you're only interested in queues.

The problem with using SSB as a 'dumb queue' is that is a very expensive queue (just think at the extra writes required on each message due to conversations and conversation groups). RECEIVE statement is expensive and basically a black box from optimization pov. You could optimize a [table used as a queue](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) a lot better than what you can do with an SSB service/queue. I reckon that SSB has an ace up its sleeves which makes it attractive even when used as a local queue, namely the [internal activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) capabilities. One may say that activation cannot be replaced with anything else (I agree, it cannot), but one must be aware of the cost and balance the pros and cons.

Comment: PS. I am aware that my answer does not address the actual question ('links to best practices')...